# `require': cannot load such file -- capybara/rspec (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I tried to test my project. It was working before and I don't know what i did to whenever i type `bundle exec rspec spec/` it says `cannot load such file -- capybara/rspec (LoadError)`. And Please I need an advice to which one is good for testing my MVC in ruby on rails as a newbie.

```
Gemfile:
------------

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
  gem 'minitest'
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'rb-inotify', '0.8.8'
  gem 'libnotify', '0.5.9'
  gem 'guard-spork', '0.3.2'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0'
  gem 'spork-testunit'
  gem 'guard-test'
  gem 'ruby-prof'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0' 
  if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /linux/
    gem 'capybara-webkit'
  end
  gem 'launchy'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
end
```

### spec_helper:

```
require 'rubygems'
#require 'factory_girl'
#uncomment the following line to use spork with the debugger
#require 'spork/ext/ruby-debug'


  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'
  require 'capybara/rspec'
  require 'capybara/rails'

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr
  config.mock_with :rspec

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  #Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
end
```

### Error:

```
/home/IN4SYSTEMS/sri.kalai/Desktop/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- capybara/rspec (LoadError)
        from /home/IN4SYSTEMS/sri.kalai/Desktop/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from /home/IN4SYSTEMS/sri.kalai/Desktop/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/IN4SYSTEMS/sri.kalai/Desktop/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from /home/IN4SYSTEMS/sri.kalai/Documents/promaster/spec/spec_helper.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/IN4SYSTEMS/sri.kalai/Documents/promaster/spec/helpers/loc/epcs_helper_spec.rb:1:in `require'
        from /home/IN4SYSTEMS/sri.kalai/Documents/promaster/spec/helpers/loc/epcs_helper_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/IN4SYSTEMS/sri.kalai/Desktop/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load'
        from /home/IN4SYSTEMS/sri.kalai/Desktop/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from /home/IN4SYSTEMS/sri.kalai/Desktop/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `map'
        from /home/IN4SYSTEMS/sri.kalai/Desktop/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load_spec_files'
        from /home/IN4SYSTEMS/sri.kalai/Desktop/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
        from /home/IN4SYSTEMS/sri.kalai/Desktop/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:66:in `rescue in run'
        from /home/IN4SYSTEMS/sri.kalai/Desktop/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:62:in `run'
        from /home/IN4SYSTEMS/sri.kalai/Desktop/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you did install all required gems? Using `bundle install` BTW did you change Gemfile, in that case you would be required to install Gems using bundle install.

You could check list of gems available by `gem list`

Regarding second part of the question, which testing API to use. It is matter of choice. You could stick with `rpsec` and if you find it falls short of your expectation, then look out for change.

Comment: hi, Thanks. I updated the question with the error list. I did bundle install. But still no luck.

Comment: Does `gem list` show capybara listed? If not then try to add manually and check if it works.

Comment: it shows the capybara (1.1.2) and capybara-webkit (0.12.1) is there in the gem list

Answer (score 0):

Try `gem query --local` to see if `capybara-screenshot` appears in your list of installed gems.  (For some reason, this rendered a different list than `gem list` for me.)

If you don't see it, then try `gem install capybara-screenshot`.  It is not included in the installation of `capybara`, so seeing `capybara` in your list of gems alone is not sufficient!

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem today and I fixed it in the following way:

- Comment in file `spec_helper.rb` 
  next raws 
  `require 'capybara/rspec'`
  `require 'capybara/rails'`,
- Remove 
  `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@olha/gems/capybara-webkit-1.1.0`
  from my HDD space.

Comment: Could you please expand this answer so it would be usable for another person?